# Write image to page with different name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to implement a simple captcha system and I wish to output an image without using its original name.

For example I would like to ouput the image file 8.gif to the page with the name captcha1.gif

I have read the various posts but I am looking for the simplest solution.

Here's what I have so far...

```
<% Html.RenderAction("OuputCaptchaImage", "Home", new { imageName = "1" }); %>

public ActionResult OuputCaptchaImage(string imageName)
{
    var dir = Server.MapPath("images/");
    var path = Path.Combine(dir, imageName + ".gif"); // Like to change name here
    return base.File(path, "image/gif");
}
```

and what I would like to render to the page

```
<img src="image/captcha1.gif" />
```

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? Not to mention the original http://www.captcha.net/ supports a good cause..

Comment: Hi Yuck, I am trying to migrate an existing implementation from classic asp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following mark-up will output the image correctly. However you still have the problem of the file name being referenced in the url.

```
<img src="<%= Url.Action("OuputCaptchaImage", "Home", new { imageName = "1" })%>" />
```

Which would output the following HTML:

```
<img src="/Home/OuputCaptchaImage?imageName=1" />
```

You could specify some other value as a parameter such as an enumeration  rather than the image name, and then modify your logic to return the correct file.

However (AFAIK) to output an image with a file name which does not exist would require an Httphandler to intercept the request and write out the image you require to the response stream.

---

**Edit**

Here is an example of using an HttpHandler to intercept the incoming request for "captcha1.gif" and streaming a different image to the response:

**Mark-up**

```
<img src="Images/captcha1.gif" />
```

**HttpHandler**

```
public class OuputCaptchaImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string imagePath =
                context.Server.MapPath(@"~\Images\1.gif");
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imagePath);

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
        bitmap.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif);

        bitmap.Dispose();              
    }
}
```

**Web.Config**

```
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="Images/captcha1.gif" type="FullyQualifiedNameSpace.OuputCaptchaImageHandler, RootNamespace" validate="false"></add>     
  </httpHandlers>
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("Images/captcha1.gif/{*pathInfo}");

    ....
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, the intention of my original code was to return file as a stream (or whatever is needed) and then I would like to render it on the page, and it is returning the file but not rendering to the page but displaying byte code instead...

Comment: Cheers - I am trying this now - never created a httpHandler before - where the proper place for the OuputCaptchaImageHandler class? in a HttpHandler Folder?

Comment: There is no restriction on this. Main thing to note is the Namespace for the Web.config. The httpHandlers section is added to the `<system.web>` section.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the http handler is kicking in to interceed on the request to Images/captcha1.gif

Comment: I thought that was the requirement. To return a different image based on the request for Images/captcha1.gif?

Comment: Sorry mistyped that - it is not interceeding I have a breakpoint in the Process Request and it is not being hit

Comment: Typed the url of image directly to see what happened and received in the error Could not load file or assembly 'RootNamespace' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @Nicholas Murray - Checkout the web.config. Ensure that your handler class is public and that the namespace is specified for the httpHandler type like so `type="FULLYQUALIFIEDNAMESPACEHERE.OuputCaptchaImageHandler, ROOTNAMESPACEHERE"` so in my test it was like so `type="MvcApplication.Handlers.OuputCaptchaImageHandler, MvcApplication"`. I've got to go out. I will check for any messages when I am back. Good luck with it, I know it works as I have tested it. :)

Comment: @Nicholas Murray - Glad it helped.